# FormData passando imagem mais objeto

Tags: .net-core

Seguindo esse link
[Post similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892706/asp-net-core-web-api-file-upload-and-form-data-multiple-parameter-passing-to-m/58735209#58735209)

É possível passar um objeto junto com um arquivo via FormData?
Eu vi que posso fazer porém não um objeto, no caso eu fiz alguns testes e deram certo, mas nesse caso do código abaixo eu quero passar minha lista de App mas chega vazio pra ele

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult UploadImage([FromForm] FileInputModel Files)
{
  return Ok();
}
public class FileInputModel 
{
  public IFormFile File { get; set; }
  public string Param { get; set; }
  public List<App> Apps { get; set; }
}
```

O que eu posso fazer nesse caso? Eu gostaria que eu pudesse manipular tudo nessa ida, para não precisar converter para json lá no meu controller.

Comment: Você está querendo enviar de um form ou Ajax, como você está enviando? (Eu imagino que seja Ajax mas fiquei na dúvida...)

Comment: Estou usando react enviando via api REST, no caso sim é AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente tem que criar um formulário com os campos com os respectivos nomes e tipos e utilizar de maneira simples [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) para enviar os dados com [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) no seu corpo (`body`) como no exemplo abaixo:

<sup>***React Rook***</sup>

---

```javascript
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function Form() {
  const formRef = useRef();
  function onSubmitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(formRef.current);
    const settings = {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default",
      body: data
    };
    const url = ""; // endereço do serviço
    fetch(url, settings)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
  return (
    <>
      <form name='form1' ref={formRef} id='form1' onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor='file'>File</label>
          <input type='file' name='File' id='File' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor='Param'>Param</label>
          <input type='text' name='Param' id='Param' />
        </div>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

<sup>***React Class***</sup>

```javascript
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Forms extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onSubmitForm = this.onSubmitForm.bind(this);
    this.formRef = React.createRef();
  }

  onSubmitForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(this.formRef.current);
    const settings = {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default",
      body: data
    };
    const url = ""; // endereço do serviço
    fetch(url, settings)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form name="form1" ref={this.formRef} id="form1" onSubmit={this.onSubmitForm}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="file">File</label>
          <input type="file" name="File" id="File" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="Param">Param</label>
          <input type="text" name="Param" id="Param" />
        </div>
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Com esses códigos tem a classe `FileInputModel` será preenchida com as informações e a imagem enviada.